# How to Redirect on Status 404 in Microsoft Azure Archive Blob

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, azure-blob-storage, http-status-code-301

When there is a call to a blob resurce than it is not exists, I need to convert **404 status** to **301 status**, to redirect user to another resource.

**Is it possible?**

For example, my blob contains theese file:

- file1.jpg
- file2.jpg
- file3.jpg

Then when user call `http://my-storage-id.blob.core.windows.net/file1.jpg` he will receive the image.
When user call `http://my-storage-id.blob.core.windows.net/file999.jpg`user will redirect to `http://my-website.com/404-image-handler`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When there is a call to a blob resurce than it is not exists, I need
>   to convert 404 status to 301 status, to redirect user to another
>   resource.
>
> Is it possible?

As of today it is not possible.